# Set Children in Prefab as individual GameObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

When spawning a Prefab, I'm trying to have each individual GameObject that makes up the Prefab run its own respective scripts. Basically, 
I want the Prefab to break after spawning; leaving individual game Objects.

I have the GameObjects in the Prefab as children of an Empty. Any suggestions.

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CreateFab : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Spawnpoint;
    public Rigidbody Prefab;

    public void OnClick()
    {
        Rigidbody RigidPrefab;
        RigidPrefab = Instantiate(Prefab, Spawnpoint.position, Spawnpoint.rotation) as Rigidbody;
    }

    public void DetachFromParent()
    {
        // Detaches the transform from its parent.
        transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

Cube Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;

public class WallClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    string path;
    public MeshRenderer mRenderer;


    public void OpenExplorer()
    {
        path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Overwrite with png", "", "png");
        GetImage();
    }

    void GetImage()
    {
        if (path != null)
        {
            UpdateImage();
        }
    }

    void UpdateImage()
    {
        byte[] imgByte = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        texture.LoadImage(imgByte);

        mRenderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
    }
}
```

Comment: Prefabs are already broken when the game is running. Changes to one spawned prefab do not affect others. If you mean unparenting them in hierarchy, set their transform.parent to null.

Comment: I added 'transform.parent to null' to the spawn script but it didn't allow me to click on each individual cube in the prefab. I'll add the code I tried...

Answer (score 0):

If you spawn a prefab, give the spawned item a reference.

```
var obj = Instantiate(prefabGameobject);
```

You can then do whatever you like with the spawned object

```
var script = obj.AddComponent<YourScript>();
```

And you can then modify the variables of your script and so on.
Your prefab will not be touched.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm more concerned with children in the prefab. I believe 'GetComponentInChildren' function seems to be the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The `transform.parent` you're using here refers to the transform of the gameobject your `CreateFab.cs` script is attached to, not the prefab's childrens (smaller cubes).

The correct way would be:

```
// Instantiate the prefab
RigidBody rigidPrefab = Instantiate(Prefab, Spawnpoint.position, Spawnpoint.rotation) as Rigidbody;

// Detach all children from the parent. Each child refers to the transform of a single cube.
foreach (Transform child in rigidPrefab.transform)
{
    child.parent = null;
}
```

Comment: So the script compiles but it still doesn't run my attached script to each individual cube on click. The same script works on individual cubes outside of a prefab. The script is suppose to upload an image onto the individual cube. Btw. Thanks for all your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Then maybe you want to show your individual scripts on the cubes too?

Comment: Where are you calling `OpenExplorer()`? Also `EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel()` is meant to be used for editor windows. Might not be suitable for anything in game. Imagine having 10 cubes and 10 open file prompts start opening.

Comment: I'm calling OpenExplorer() on each cube. I found another script that may be helpful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHTJyfJy43Y

Comment: 'GetComponentInChildren' function seems to be the right way to go. I'll update when I find the answer.